# Busettii electric questions

Tags: electric-bike

Anyone know which wires come out of this controller?  One is not connected and I don't know where it goes!  Thanks so much![image: ![Throttle]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eT7W.jpg)

Comment: The same controller is used on freego as well. I haven't opened it up, but have opened up a nearby junction box (at the stem)  and have a vague recollection that there was a wire not connected in there. More details would help: where is the disconnected wire? What colour? What works and what doesn't?

Comment: Based on your photo, your brake levers have electric-cutoff leads to turn the motor off while braking ?  Do they go to both sides or just one?

Comment: @Criggie now I'm at a big screen you're right.  The freego again uses very similar components (Tektro), and the cables to the cutoff switches go to the junction box I mention in my previous comment.  This is just the UI for the motor controller, which is located elsewhere (below the battery near the BB on the bike I know).  What I haven't checked is whether it's just switches and wires, or if there's a microcontroller in there to multiplex the signals.  This should be easy to figure out from the number of wires, but I *think* the cutoff switches are wired to the real controller...

Comment: ...It's possible that the stray wire is not used in your configuration.  The model I'm familiar with has a throttle, which isn't allowed to be sold anymore in the UK (a pity as the bike has a habit of kicking in the pedal assist unexpectedly when timing a gap in traffic or shifting down while coasting to a stop)

Comment: The stray wire comes directly out of the controller and goes down into the bottom tube of the frame, at least that's where I found it, connected to nothing.  To answer your question about what works and what doesn't, I bought the bike used thinking it would be an easy fix but after more than a year of tinkering with it often on I still cannot get it to work at all. The battery measuresA solid 36 V on my meter,  but the display pictured above blinks as if it has low power.  The pedal assist magnet disc was broken and I replace that as well as the sensor with no change. Any help would be greatly